# Вычислить линии из геометрии three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Есть объект, который я загружаю `OBJLoader.js`

У него есть геометрия, с атрибутами `normal`, `position`, `uv` (`Float32Array`).
Как я могу вычислить из геометрии все линии которые есть в ней, чтобы потом проверить пересечение этих линий с другим объектом?

```
var objectLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
function loadObject( model ) {
    objectLoader.load( model,
        function ( object ) {
            object.children.forEach( function ( child ) {
                getGeometryLines( child.geometry );

            });
            scene.add( object );
        },
        onProgress, onError);
}

function getGeometryLines( geometry ) {
    var uv = geometry.getAttribute('uv');
    var normalArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( uv.array );

    for(var i = 0; i < normalArray.length; i++) {
     //...
    }
}
```

Comment: А "другой объект" - это что? Какое-то объемное тело или плоскость?

Comment: Да, другой объект это плоскость с точки (0, 0, 0).

Comment: Я почему-то так и думал, что нужно найти точки пересечения с плоскостью ) Тогда посмотрите вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353447/4045502. Разница лишь в том, что в вашем случае нужно находить точки вершин в гранях буферной геометрии, а не обычной. Тут уже вариантов - масса. Можно конвертировать буферную геометрию в обычную и использовать решение из моего ответа сразу, либо, как уже говорил - через индексы искать вершины граней у буферной геометрии. jsfiddle прилагается в конце ответа )

Comment: :) Да, это то что нужно. Не нашел( Искренне благодарен! Извините, может не правильно выразился.

Comment: Хотел спросить еще об одном, если позволите. Таким образом у меня есть массив точек пересечения (для наглядности, как было выше указано я их соединил [ http://joxi.ru/BA00n5LIJxKGDA ] ). Плоскость проходит в трех местах. Не подскажите как можно эти точки сгруппировать между собой, грубо говоря разделить на три массива, там где проходит плоскость? Или может есть где подобное рациональное решение?

Comment: Специально под это дело решений не искал. Но навскидку: берем точку из массива (допустим, самую первую), ищем, какой грани она принадлежит, ищем вторую точку, принадлежащую этой же грани, помечаем точки, как найденные, дальше перебираем оставшиеся точки, которые не помечены, как найденные, и ищем точку с координатами, равными второй найденной точки, если нашли - определяем какой грани она принадлежит, ищем вторую точку на этой грани... и так далее в цикле.

Comment: Когда пришли к тому, что еще остались непомеченные точки, а смежных граней больше нет, считаем, что закрыли один контур. Переходим к следующей непомеченной точке и повторяем цикл поиска точек и смежных граней. Как-то так ) Не проверял, но если у вас получится - отпишитесь )

Comment: По вашему описанию не получилось :( Попробовал по такому принципу - отсортировал точки по расстоянию друг от друга, и добавлял в новые массивы по условию: если точка ближе к следующей отсортированной чем к начальной то добавляем следующую, иначе замыкаем и в новый добавляем - https://jsfiddle.net/qbdo8bwp/7/ . Но, как то не очень.. :(

Comment: контуры могут располагаться близко друг от друга, через это - ближайшие точки двух контуров могут попасть под ваше условие )

Comment: Даа.. ) Это правда :(

Comment: Видел ваш вопрос в англоязычном сегменте ) Попробую чего-нибудь придумать.

Comment: Да, не смог ничего придумать( Большое спасибо Вам! Я пошел по простому пути. Я взял и нарисовал сам эту линию в редакторе) Идея заключалась в том, есть замкнутая закрученная геометрия (как выше на скрине), и что бы порезать ее по кругу, найти точки пересечения, из них взять производную и соединить все в новую линию, по которой будет передвигаться с помощью мышки другой объект.

Comment: А можно картинку с результатом, для лучшего понимания? )

Comment: Вы за линию? http://joxi.ru/l2ZRn45swjJDp2 показал как вообще и что я хотел, что бы можно было загружать подобные модели и обрабатывать таким способом. Я новичок в этом деле, не обессудьте :)

Comment: Глядя на картинку. Креативность - дело личное, но подобную замкнутую, грубо говоря, "трубу" можно построить средствами Three.js (помогут `THREE.TubeGeometry()` и `THREE.CatmullRomCurve3()`, где сплайн Catmull-Rom - есть основа всего, и именно ее можно использовать как путь по которому можно перемещать другой объект).

Comment: Мм, не знал ) Спасибо за подобную информацию. Вот эти так называемые "трубы", к сожалению не я придумываю, а мне уже они приходят, а какие они придут, этого я уже не знаю, но по условию что они замкнуты и теперь с линией =)

Comment: Я как-то не могу найти вопрос в англоязычном сегменте теперь ) Вы его удалили? )

Comment: У меня есть решение (которое еще в общем-то можно пооптимизировать), но раз интереса уже нет - пусть пока полежит :)

Comment: Да ( Никто не интересовался данным вопросом, не было идей, подумал, что бы не засорять лишний раз ( вопросами без ответов ) та и удалил )

Ах, искушаете :) Интерес есть )

Comment: Тогда верните вопрос в том сегменте - там хоть есть вероятность получить больше репутации, чем здесь (да, вот такой шкурный интерес) :)

Comment: Ну, как Вы раньше писали, это дело личное :)  Вернул ^^

Comment: Ответил в том сегменте )

Comment: Да, да, вижу ) Спасибо Вам! Отметил. Вы все таки реализовали по Вашему принципу, это работает хорошо. Добавьте ответ также в тот где Вы писали о пересечении с плоскостью :)